# Generic/polymorphic iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

What is the best way to implement getIterator? Depending on a condition, I want to return the corresponding iterator.

```
// global variables
vector<int> myVector;
set<int> mySet;

vector<int>/set<int>::iterator getIterator(bool someCondition) {
    if (someCondition) return mySet.begin();
    else return myVector.begin();
}
```

Please resist 'wise' responses like "don't use global variables" etc. I just want to know if there is a way to "generalize" both set and vector iterators, this example is just crafted to keep things simple.

Cheers

Comment: Did you mean to declare `mySet` as `std::set<int>`? As currently stated, you'd just `return (condition? mySet: myVector).begin();` as you are effectively doing.

Comment: Can `someCondition` be evaluated at compile-time?

Comment: There's [`any_iterator`](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html), but I've never used it myself.

Comment: Look into `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. C++ is a statically-typed language. That means that the type of a function's or a method's return value is declared at compile time, not at run time.

Other languages, like Perl for example, are dynamically typed. A Perl function can, sometimes, return a scalar value, like an integer. Other times it can return a reference (a pointer), or a list or a hash (a std::vector, or a std::map). But C++ does not work this way.

So, if you need to write dynamically-typed code, you'll need to use some other language, other than C++.

The only thing that you can do here, in C++ is to declare this function as returning some type that can be converted to either one.

For example:

```
class return_value {

public:

    enum { vector, set} type_t;

    type_t type;

    std::vector<int>::iterator v_iter;
    std::set<int>::iterator s_iter;
};

return_value getIterator(bool someCondition) {
    // ...
}
```

Your `getIterator()` function would then construct a `return_value` instance, initializing either its `v_iter` or `s_iter` member, and initialize its `type` member to either `return_value::vector` or `return_value::set`, so that `getIterator()`'s caller can examine the return value, and determine what kind of an iterator is being returned.

Different approaches are also possible. If, for example, the type of the return value can be determined from `getIterator()`'s parameters, it might be possible to implement a statically-typed solution using templates and specialization.

Comment: Hmmmmm, but the return type could be polymorphic, in which case, c++ being statically-typed language would have no problem.

E.g. if set and vector both were derived from a base class Iterable, then I could simply return Iterable<int>::iterator. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to resort to allocating a polymorphic object on the heap. That introduces additional complexities into the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, iterators can be generalized, but you will probably need to write a wrapper class. There are several options for implementing it. Obviously, you will need to store an actual iterator inside the class and have a way to determine, which iterator it is. For example:

```
class MyIter {
...
private:
    union {
        std::vector<int>::iterator vec_iter;
        std::set<int>::iterator set_iter;
    }
    bool is_vec_iter; /* or like in an example above, enum { vector, set} type_t; */
};
```

It should be pretty obvious, how to construct an object of such class. The interesting part is implementing the interface, i.e. dereferencing, incrementing, comparing iterators.

Probably a good thing to take a look at is boost::iterator_facade: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html. It's a helper template, which implements most of iterator's operations using only few methods for dereferencing and traversal which you must provide. Even if you decide to implement everything from scratch, iterator_facade is a good example to start with.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't types in a union with non-trivial default constructor. While a vector iterator is most likely just a pointer (and thus has a trivial default constructor), it most likely works, but there is no guarantee. And a set iterator is most likely not just a pointer.

Comment: This restriction has been relaxed in C++11. If older version must be used, an additional level of indirection can be used, or, better some type erasure method like boost::variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it, and use polymorphism. Here is an example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class GenericIterator_helper_base {
        friend class GenericIterator;
    public:
        virtual ~GenericIterator_helper_base() = default;
        virtual int operator*() = 0;
        virtual void pre_inc() = 0;
};

template <typename IT>
class GenericIterator_helper_tmpl : public GenericIterator_helper_base {
    public:
        GenericIterator_helper_tmpl(IT &&it_) : it(it_) { }
        virtual ~GenericIterator_helper_tmpl() = default;
        virtual int operator*() { return *it; }
        virtual void pre_inc() { ++it; }
    private:
        IT it;
};

class GenericIterator {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        GenericIterator(T &&it) : helper(new GenericIterator_helper_tmpl<T>(std::move(it))) { }
        int operator*() { return helper->operator*(); }
        GenericIterator &operator++() { helper->pre_inc(); return *this; }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<GenericIterator_helper_base> helper;
};

vector<int> myVector{1, 2};
set<int> mySet{3, 4};

GenericIterator
getIterator(bool cond) {
    if (cond) {
        return GenericIterator(mySet.begin());
    } else {
        return GenericIterator(myVector.begin());
    }
}

int main() {
    auto it1 = getIterator(true);
    auto it2 = getIterator(false);

    cout << *it1 << endl;
    ++it1;
    cout << *it1 << endl;

    cout << *it2 << endl;
    ++it2;
    cout << *it2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually meant to write

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
std::set<int>    mySet;
```

... and you want to get an iterator conditionally iterating over one of the sequence, my immediate reaction is: "don't do it!" First of all, I found it extremely rare that `std::set<T>` is useful for anything and the few cases where it might be useful, `std::unordered_set<T>` is a better alternative. However, that's somewhat of a tangent.

The more important thing is: the whole point of Programming is to make things fast and run-time decisions on low-level operations are bound to interfere with performance. You're much better off redesigning the system to throw out uses of `std::set<T>` or `std::unordered_set<T>` and consistently use a `std::vector<T>`. If necessary, use appropriate set-like operations on the instances which must behave like a set.

OK, still reading? Not got: I'm serious about the stuff above. Consider it before moving on! There isn't really a good approach to use iterators over different containers, at least, not STL iterators. STL iterators are meant to be fast and as a result they use individual low-level operations for each of the essential operations (advance, compare, access). If you stick with that interface, you'll create a performance problem: there is a reason why interfaces using a dynamically polymorphic approach use an `Enumerable` interface (or something like that) which folds all three operations into one: to safe on dynamic dispatches! (so, you should really, really consider not doing what is outline below)

OK, still reading, i.e., you have painted yourself into a corner. Well, here is enough rope to hang performance but possibly get you out of this tight spot: with C++11 you *can* use `union`s containing class types. You'll just need to make sure you deal with them appropriately during construction and destruction. You can use that to dispatch to a suitable dynamic interface without having to allocate memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <new>


namespace demo {
    template <typename It0, typename It1>
    class joint_iterator {
    public:
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It0>::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef value_type* pointer;
        typedef value_type& reference;

    private:
        struct dyn_base {
            dyn_base() = default;
            dyn_base(dyn_base const&) = default;
            virtual ~dyn_base() {}
            virtual bool equal(dyn_base const* other) const = 0;
            virtual void increment() = 0;
            virtual value_type access() = 0;
            virtual int index() const = 0;
        };
        template <typename It, int Index>
        struct dyn_it: dyn_base {
            dyn_it(It it): it(it) {}
            It it;
            bool equal(dyn_base const* other) const override {
                return this->it == static_cast<dyn_it<It, Index> const*>(other)->it;
            }
            void increment() override { ++this->it; }
            value_type access() override { return *this->it; }
            int index() const override { return Index; }
        };
        union it_rep{
            it_rep() {}
            ~it_rep() {}
            int         dummy;
            dyn_it<It0, 0> it0;
            dyn_it<It1, 1> it1;
        } rep;
        dyn_base* it;

    public:
        ~joint_iterator() { this->it->~dyn_base(); }
        joint_iterator(joint_iterator const& other) {
            if (other.it->index() == 0) {
                new(&this->rep.it0) dyn_it<It0, 0>(other.rep.it0); it = &this->rep.it0;
            }
            else {
                new(&this->rep.it1) dyn_it<It1, 1>(other.rep.it1); it = &this->rep.it1;
            }
        }
        joint_iterator& operator=(joint_iterator const& other);
        joint_iterator(It0 it0) { new(&this->rep.it0) dyn_it<It0, 0>(it0); it = &this->rep.it0; }
        joint_iterator(It1 it1) { new(&this->rep.it1) dyn_it<It1, 1>(it1); it = &this->rep.it1; }

        bool operator== (joint_iterator const& it) const {
            return this->it->equal(it.it);
        }
        bool operator!= (joint_iterator const& it) const {
            return !(*this == it);
        }
        value_type operator*() const { return this->it->access(); }
        joint_iterator& operator++() { this->it->increment(); return *this; }
        joint_iterator operator++(int) { joint_iterator rc(*this); this->operator++(); return rc; }
    };
}

int main(int ac, char*[])
{
    std::set<int>    s{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
    std::vector<int> v{ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 };

    typedef demo::joint_iterator<std::set<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator> joint_iterator;
    std::copy(ac == 2? joint_iterator(s.begin()): joint_iterator(v.begin()),
              ac == 2? joint_iterator(s.end()): joint_iterator(v.end()),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This code is lacking some method implementations (e.g., the assignment operator is missing) and takes a few short-cuts with respect to figuring out types. It isn't thoroughly tested but, at least, works with a recent gcc and clang. I haven't measured the performance of this implementation (yet?) but I fully expect that it - er - isn't great.

Comment: The point about set vs. unordered_set is ridiculous! You need an ordered set a lot of times, both are very different data structures with different use cases.

Comment: @turing_machine: I perfectly understand the differences between these data structures and your experience my vary but I have no use for a modifiable data structure which keeps its constants elements sorted and is rather slow as a result. Even something like `std::unordered_set<T>` is rare in the code I'm working (which is a rather substantial code base). All uses of `std::set<T>` have been removed because they are unnecessary slow and the "feature" of the elements being sorted either was never used or is achieved faster `std::sort()`ing a `std::vector<T>` upon need.

Comment: Lol @ "it doesn't come up often in my code, therefore, it isn't useful", nice. :)

It's a shame if you have removed them. Trees are one of the most useful (and fastest) data structures in Computer Science if used properly. Unfortunately, many coders don't use them as often as they should because of poor understanding of the fundamentals.

Comment: @turing_machine: you claim I don't understand trees and/or the trade-offs between alternatives of trees? Well, rest assured that we measured the performance of our life system and it made a difference, although a small one: `std::set<T>`s were used rarely so it didn't have much opportunity to make a big difference. Also, note that I didn't even claim that they are never useful (although I still have to find a use for them where the alternatives are not better).

Comment: @turing_machine: ... and just for, here some graphs comparing alternative implementation involving `std::set<T>`s (the length of the bars represent time takens, i.e., short is good): [searching in data structures of different sizes](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cputube/search-integer.html) and [iterating over a sequence](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cputube/sequence-iteration.html) (these benchmarks are not those used for our live system, of course, just some examples to argue why the work should be done).

Comment: My last comment on futile discussion.

@Dietmar: I didn't claim any such thing. I agree that similar or better worst-time behavior can be achieved using vectors and unordered_sets instead of sets. But in many cases, its way more elegant to use sets directly.

Benjamin: Its not a misrepresentation of Dietmar's argument. It's clear that the reason given for not finding sets useful is based on experience.